# What could be causing my Flutter Firebase Storage file upload to suddenly fail with an 'unknown' error?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, firebase-storage

In a Flutter App I want to upload an Image to firebase storage. It was working yesterday on iOS Simulator and I didn't change the coding. Since today in the morning the same functionality throws an error. But with the error I can't do anything.
Error Message:
code: "unknown"
message: "An unknown error occured, please check the server response".
plugin: "firebase_storage"

firebase_storage: 11.2.2

Upload Function

```
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, Unit>> uploadFile(File file, String? name) async {
    try {
      final userStorage = await firebaseStorage.userStorage();

      final fileName = _getFileName(file, name);

      final fileReference = userStorage.child(fileName);
      await fileReference.putFile(file);

      
      return right(unit);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.code.contains("PERMISSION_DENIED")) {
        return left(InsufficientPermissions());
      } else {
        return left(UnexpectedFailure());
      }
    }
  }
```

I would expect that the upload would work again as yesterday. I tried it on a different development machine and updated the firebase_storage plugin to the latest version. Run again pod install but nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

Well problem solved it by itself, it's working again nothing changed